# How to close the Tkinter window when the mouse clicked away from the Tkinter window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Good days all, I am new here, and I have stuck the problem a few days a problem currently with Tkinter, I have done some research about how to close Tkinter window when the mouse has clicked away from it but there are not much information to do so.

So, my problem is how to close the Tkinter window when the mouse clicked outside the Tkinter? I have tried the method of `FocusOut` to my Tkinter. However, I have tried to bind with root, it will close the window even though I clicked inside the frame widget. Then, I `bind` with the frame, the Tkinter will close when I clicked outside the Tkinter. Therefore, I have proved that the idea to close the Tkinter is works so far.

Then a new problem has happened, when I clicked the `Combobox` widget in the window, the window will close also. Is there any better solution to prove this concept?

Here is the code to indicate my problem.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import StringVar, ttk,messagebox


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Sample Window")
root.minsize(300,350)

info_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text = "Information")
info_frame.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5 , fill = "both",expand=True)

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(info_frame)
person1tab = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(person1tab,text = "Person1")
tabControl.pack(expand=1,fill="both")

person2tab = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(person2tab,text = "Person2")
tabControl.pack(expand=1,fill="both")

fname_var = tk.StringVar()
lname_var = tk.StringVar()
gender_var = tk.StringVar()
age_var = tk.IntVar()

fname_label = tk.Label(person1tab, text = "First name:").pack(padx=5,pady=3)
fname_entry = tk.Entry(person1tab, textvariable=fname_var).pack(padx=5,pady=3)

lname_label = tk.Label(person1tab, text = "Last name:").pack(padx=5,pady=3)
lname_entry = tk.Entry(person1tab, textvariable=lname_var).pack(padx=5,pady=3)

gender_label = tk.Label(person1tab, text = "Gender:").pack(padx=5,pady=3)
gender_combo =  ttk.Combobox(person1tab, textvariable=gender_var,state='readonly')
gender_combo['values'] = ('Male','Female')
gender_combo.current(0)

gender_combo.pack(padx=5,pady=3)

age_label = tk.Label(person1tab, text = "Age:").pack(padx=5,pady=3)
age_label = tk.Entry(person1tab, textvariable=age_var).pack(padx=5,pady=3)

page2label = tk.Label(person2tab,text = "This is tab 2.").pack(padx=5,pady=3)

def lossfocus(event):
    root.quit()
    pass

tabControl.bind('<FocusOut>', lossfocus)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry but I think you should stop wanting to do this.  It is a total violation of the basic concept of a windowing system.  Your application is supposed to share the system with other applications, and as such it should be unaware that the user has started to interact with another application.   Your application should only close when the user wants it to close, by clicking on the "X" in the window bar or on some button intended for this purpose.

Comment: Try using `info_frame.bind('<Leave>', lossfocus)`.

Comment: @Paul: You're making a lot of assumptions. The tkinter window might be one of several the application itself has created. Besides, rules are made to be broken…it's called progress. `;¬)`

Comment: @martineau, Hi Sir, Thanks for your reply, I have tried the 'Leave' event but when I clicked the combobox again, the window will be close also which I don't want that to be happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still bind `<FocusOut>` on root window, but you need to check:

- whether the widget that trigger this event is root window
- no other widget in this root window getting the focus:

```py
def lossfocus(event):
    if event.widget is root:
        # check which widget getting the focus
        w = root.tk.call('focus')
        if not w:
            # not widget in this window
            root.destroy()
```

Comment: @acw1688 Wonderful!, Thanks Sir, you have solved my problem !!!